# Setting the value of an array index

Tags: java, arrays

Hello Everyone,

I was trying to work out how to set Diff[0] equal to the sum of an equation and I found that when:

```
int a = 0;

System.out.println(Data[0] - Data[1]);   //The calculation is possible and correct

Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];   //But this line outputs a value of 0

Diff[0] = Data[0] - Data[1];   //I have also tried this but still a value of 0
```

Here is my code: No Errors

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Numbers;
    int A;
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4, f = 5, g = 6, h = 7, i = 8, j = 9, k = 10, l = 11, m = 12, n = 13, o = 14, p = 15, q = 16, r = 17;
    int num;
    int lengthOfArray;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Stone Pile");
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of stones:");
    Numbers = numbers.nextInt();

    int Data[] = new int[Numbers];
    for (A = 0; A < Data.length; A++) {
        for (num = 1; num < Numbers; num++) {
            int numGen = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 21);
            Data[A] = numGen;
        }
    }

    lengthOfArray = Data.length;

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println(Data.length + " This is the length of the Data Array");

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println(Data[0]);
    System.out.println(Data[1]);
    System.out.println(Data[2]);
    System.out.println(Data[3]);
    System.out.println(Data[4]);
    System.out.println(Data[5]);
    System.out.println(Data[6]);
    System.out.println(Data[7]);
    System.out.println(Data[8]);
    System.out.println(Data[9]);

    System.out.println("\n");

    int Diff[] = new int[20];

    System.out.println(Diff.length + " This is length of the Diff Array");

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println(Diff[0]);
    System.out.println(Diff[1]);
    System.out.println(Diff[2]);
    System.out.println(Diff[3]);
    System.out.println(Diff[4]);
    System.out.println(Diff[5]);
    System.out.println(Diff[6]);
    System.out.println(Diff[7]);
    System.out.println(Diff[8]);
    System.out.println(Diff[9]);

    switch (lengthOfArray) {
        case 2:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            break;

        case 3:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            break;

        case 4:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            break;

        case 5:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            break;

        case 6:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            break;

        case 7:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            break;

        case 8:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            break;

        case 9:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            break;

        case 10:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            break;

        case 11:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            break;

        case 12:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            break;

        case 13:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            break;

        case 14:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            break;

        case 15:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            Diff[n] = Data[13] - Data[14];
            break;

        case 16:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            Diff[n] = Data[13] - Data[14];
            Diff[o] = Data[14] - Data[15];
            break;

        case 17:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            Diff[n] = Data[13] - Data[14];
            Diff[o] = Data[14] - Data[15];
            Diff[p] = Data[15] - Data[16];
            break;

        case 18:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            Diff[n] = Data[13] - Data[14];
            Diff[o] = Data[14] - Data[15];
            Diff[p] = Data[15] - Data[16];
            Diff[q] = Data[16] - Data[17];
            break;

        case 19:
            Diff[a] = Data[0] - Data[1];
            Diff[b] = Data[1] - Data[2];
            Diff[c] = Data[2] - Data[3];
            Diff[d] = Data[3] - Data[4];
            Diff[e] = Data[4] - Data[5];
            Diff[f] = Data[5] - Data[6];
            Diff[g] = Data[6] - Data[7];
            Diff[h] = Data[7] - Data[8];
            Diff[i] = Data[8] - Data[9];
            Diff[j] = Data[9] - Data[10];
            Diff[k] = Data[10] - Data[11];
            Diff[l] = Data[11] - Data[12];
            Diff[m] = Data[12] - Data[13];
            Diff[n] = Data[13] - Data[14];
            Diff[o] = Data[14] - Data[15];
            Diff[p] = Data[15] - Data[16];
            Diff[q] = Data[16] - Data[17];
            Diff[r] = Data[16] - Data[18];
            break;
    }
```

Output:

20 This is the length of the Data Array

9
17
5
20
20
17
17
3
7
6

20 This is length of the Diff Array

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

The numbers in the Diff array should not be all 0's

I wondering if there's a way I can set the value of an array index, based off an equation.

Comment: have you type this all?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to achieve this with loops:

```
for(int i=0; i<Data.length-1; i++){
    Diff[i] = Data[i]-Data[i+1];
    System.out.println(Diff[i]);
}
```

These four lines could replace your entire switch statement and all of the "println(Diff..." lines. (Note that the reason you're getting the wrong Diff output is because you print the Diffs before you set their values)

Comment: if the input is `2` the OP don't want to calculate all the index values

Comment: Not clear what you mean. This is exactly equivalent to the given code.

Comment: just look at the switch code carefully though it can be rectified

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the ugly code, you should move the stub of printing `Diff` array **after** the `switch` stub. You printed `Diff` array out before assigning it with values.